# Extract kwargs and args based on positions in another function

Tags: python, function, args, keyword-argument

I want to model a function's arguments around another function. So for example, if I have:

```
def f(arg1, arg2=0, otherargs=...):
    # Does something.
```

I want to then create a function that can use the same args:

```
def g(*):  # Or however best to parameterize.
    arg1 =  # Extract arg1 value.
    arg2 =  # Extract arg2 value, if provided.
    # Do something with arg1 and arg2.
    f_result = f(arg1, arg2, otherargs)
    # Do something else with f_result and return.
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with [`inspect.getcallargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getcallargs): it takes the function, and the args and kwargs, and returns the dictionary of the arguments. With f and g defined as above, this would look like:

```py
import inspect
def f(arg1, arg2=0, otherargs=...):
    # Does something.
    return

def g(*args, **kwargs):  # Or however best to parameterize.
    kwargs = inspect.getcallargs(f, *args, **kwargs)
    arg1 = kwargs["arg1"] # Extract arg1 value.
    arg2 = kwargs["arg2"] # Extract arg2 value, if provided.
    otherargs = kwargs["otherargs"]
    # Do something with arg1 and arg2.
    f_result = f(arg1, arg2, otherargs)
    # Do something else with f_result and return.
```